# To open new Excel sheet from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I creating Silverlight App, while exporting grid into excel, I need to open a new Excel sheet but I was not able to open a new Excel within silverlight. I am using Telerik controls, in their examples , they are saving a new excel and then exoporting data. But my client need not want the save operation performed  before exporting the Grid data. 
The flow should be like the one below:
1. Open new excel  (Excel should be in front of the screen) 
2. export data
3. Saving the excel is enduser 's choice .

The end user may or may not save the Excel sheet according to their need.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: you want to open the excell sheet and then fill the data from silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void button8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic excelApp;
        excelApp = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        dynamic workbook = excelApp.workbooks;
        workbook.Add();
        dynamic sheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;
        dynamic cell = null;
        int index = 1;
        foreach (unite emp in dataGrid1.ItemsSource)
        {
            cell = sheet.Cells[index, 1];
            cell.Value = emp.unite_description;
            cell = sheet.Cells[index, 2];
            //cell.Value = emp.EmployeeId;
            //cell = sheet.Cells[index, 3];
            //cell.Value = emp.Department;
            index++;
        }
     }
```

This is what I found when I had the same problem as you and it's working as you asked. (Declaring variables as dynamic is probably not necessary)

Comment: Please tell me if the answer was useful to you (and validate it if it was)

Answer (score 0):

Use excellite library. it is an appropriate free tool for reading and writing Excel files.
you can find it hear:  http://excellite.codeplex.com/